# How to build back a splitted and then updated string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With the follwing code I split a string, create a list, and given a specific pattern, substitute a random char with another one

```
import string
import sys
import re
import json
import random
import itertools

comando = "/bin/curl http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d 'a=a&b=b'"
payloadMUT1 = comando
payloadMUT3 = re.split(r'/', payloadMUT1)
filteredarray = []

for i in payloadMUT3:
    #i don't want special chars to get involved in the substitution process
    filteredarray.extend(re.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', i))

new_array = []

for a in payloadMUT3:
    if a in filteredarray:

        randomIndex = int(random.random() * len(a))
        randomChar = a[randomIndex]  
        payloadMUT4 = a.replace(randomChar, '?')
        new_array.append(payloadMUT4)
    else:
        new_array.append(a)

print('/'.join(new_array))
```

Output:

```
/?in/curl http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d 'a=a&b=b'
```

How do I assemble all those values to build the whole ( updated ) string back?

This is the output I'm looking for:

```
/?in/cu?l http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d 'a=a&b=b'
```

PS: this is just an example; it could be everything else, also a string with multiple slashes and spaces

Some more examples with complex strings:

```
/bin/find . -type f -iname "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -i '[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]' {} \; -> /b?n/fi?d . -type f -iname "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -i '[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]' {} \;
/usr/bin/ls | /bin/grep "something" -> /?sr/b?n/l? | /bi?/gre? "something"
```

Comment: Can your task be restated as "randomly replace alpha characters with a question mark"?

Comment: If you look at your `payloadMUT3` and `filteredarray` values it's pretty clear why only a letter in `bin` gets randomly replaced. `a in filteredarray` is only true once.

Comment: @Nick but if for example i have an input like that: /usr/bin/ls | /bin/grep 'something' && /bin/cat /etc/passwd" -> it becomes "/us?/bi?/ls | /b?n/grep 'something' && /b?n/cat /e?c/p?sswd" , it happens more than one time, but still not everywhere it should be. how would you fix it?

Comment: @JonSG i wish it could be that simple! ahah

Comment: Would it work by replacing `if a in filteredarray` with `if any(x in a for x in filteredarray if a)`? That would check if any string in the filtered array is present in a part of `a` and also checks if `a` is falsy.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal it does not work, it generates messed up strings sadly, for example: "/usr/bin/ls | /bin/grep 'something' && /bin/cat /etc/passwd" -> /?sr/?in/ls?|?/bi?/grep 'somet?ing' && /b?n/c?t /e?c/?asswd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to replace a random letter in any word that follows a `/` in the input string. You can do that with a regex substitution, using a replacer function to replace a random character in the match:

```py
import re

strs = [
    """/bin/curl http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d 'a=a&b=b'""",
    """/bin/find . -type f -iname "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -i '[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]' {} \;""",
    '''/usr/bin/ls | /bin/grep "something"'''
]

def replacer(m):
    a = m.group(0)
    randomIndex = int(random.random() * len(a))
    randomChar = a[randomIndex]  
    return a.replace(randomChar, '?')

for s in strs:
    res = re.sub(r'(?<=/)[a-z]+', replacer, s)
    print(res)
```

Sample output:

```
/?in/cu?l http://111.111.111.111:1111/ -X POST -d 'a=a&b=b'
/b?n/?ind . -type f -iname "*.stuff" -exec egrep -H -i '[a-z]\.[a-z]\.[a-z]' {} \;
/?sr/bi?/l? | /b?n/gr?p "something"
```

Comment: One last thing: when i went back to use the function 'input' ( 'comando = input("...")' ) rather than 'strs = list', the output is totally messed up! ahah

Comment: this is the ouput, but imagine every char in a new line:
/
b
i
n
/
c
a
t
 
/
e
t
c
/
p
a
s
s
w
d

Comment: @jagghy I don't see how that could happen with my code. If I do `s = input("...")` and input `/bin/cat /etc/passwd` and then do `re.sub(r'(?<=/)[a-z]+', replacer, s)` I get `'/?in/ca? /et?/?asswd'`

Comment: still many thanks for helping me! i don't know either ahah but i fixed it. i was trying the same logic, but rather than with everything between a "/", everything between a "\". so, for example: c:\windows\System32\more.com C:\windows\win.ini ->  c:\window?\Sy?tem32\mor?.com C:\?indo?s\?in.ini. I changed this "(?<=/)[a-z]+" to this "(?<=\\\)[a-z]+", but it does not work corretly everytime. for example, sometimes that script produces: c:\windows\?ystem32\m?re.com C:\windows?win.ini...

Comment: @jagghy you probably need to either use `r'(?<=\\)[a-zA-Z]+'` or `r'(?i)(?<=\\)[a-z]+'` so it will also match words with uppercase letters in them

Comment: the uppercase letters are matched, if you notice in the last example "\?ystem32" \ is "\System32\".. but the previous directory "\windows\" does not cointain any replaced char. also the last '\' has been wrongly replaced in windows?win.ini that is windows\win.ini

Comment: @jagghy I can't reproduce that behaviour on my system. I always get one letter in each word replaced, and no other characters. It might be worth asking another question with the exact code you are using